# Retopology philosophy

Tags: modeling, topology, dynamic-topology, retopology, remesh

[image: Ears]

On the right is an ear from a full head.  Note the tri geometry throughout.
On the left is an attempt at redoing the head into quad-based topology.

During the process, I tried Dyntopo in Sculpt mode.  This instantly generated tris everywhere.  Then I tried Remesh, and got the quad-based head on the left.  Unfortunately, there aren't any usable loops.

Is there a better method of retopology that maintains quads and loops if the end goal is rigging for animation?  Should I be looking into Multi-res?

Or am I chasing my tail trying to achieve something that isn't necessary?

PS- I'm experimenting with Bsurfaces add-on.  Might be some potential there...

Comment: "Is there a better method of retopology that maintains quads and loops if the end goal is rigging for animation?"  Yes, there is manual retopology.  It is your only real option for character animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus seems to be that retopology of characters is best done by creating a new copy of the character using shrinkwrap modifiers and placing quads roughly by hand.

There are tools to aid quad base retopology, even for character animation.  Many people are fans of [retopoflow](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow)

One thing almost everyone seems to agree on is that it's not something you can do well on complex meshes by using sculpturing tools.